# Upgrading ruby in an environment that uses passenger & RVM with deployment handled by Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger, capistrano3

I'm trying to find a set of best practices for how to handle upgrading ruby in an environment that uses passenger & rvm (installed by deploy user) whereby deployments are handled by Capistrano.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

- On server I install the ruby that I want (e.g. rvm install 2.1.6)
- In Gemfile I change `'ruby 2.1.5'` to `'ruby 2.1.6'`
- In config/deploy/production.rb I add `set :rvm_ruby_version, "2.1.6"`
- I update my nginx passenger config on the server so that passenger_ruby now points to ruby 2.1.6 for the specific virtual host but I do not restart nginx yet.
- I deploy (bundle exec cap production deploy) and just when the deploy
  finishes I restart nginx on the server.

Is there a better way to do this?

Note that I'm using Rails 4.2.1, Capistrano 3.2.1, and passenger 5.0.6